# Visual Studio cant link on 32 bit but can on 64bit

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, compilation, linker, 32bit-64bit

I created a project and as I always do I created 2 platforms (64 and 32 bit) (this is a DLL).
I wrote the code and tested it and everything went great (I always test on 64bit configuration) but as I wanted to test on my 32bit XP VM I struggle a LINK problem.

I am using the API WSASelectEvent in my code (as a lot of other WSA/Winsock apis) but in 32 bit configuration and only in 32 bit configuration the linker refuse to find _WSASelectEvent.

I get the well known LNK2001 error :

> "error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _WSAEventSelect"

I sure link to ws2_32.lib and I sure include winsock2.h as I use other apis (such as WSAStartup and WSACleanup and structs and whatnot in my code, obviously to use winsockets).

so knowing me liking to mess around with configuration mid-work (this is a rather small project nothing too big) I decided ill go for sure and created a new project in visual studio place the code in and create a new platform to compile in (with the GUI of-course)
but I've got the same results.

I have been for 2-3 hours surfing the net to no fix and I even tried comparing the compile command line and link command line which apart of the normal /MACHINE:x64/x86 and target folders is exactly the same.

do you maybe know this problem or a solution to it?

*NOTE:: intellisense warn me about this and visual studio wont suggest parameters list when WSASelectEvent( is written, but "Go to Definition" sure takes me to Winsock2.h.*

Comment: Perhaps this is issue of headerfile inclusion. `winsock vs winsock2`.

Comment: I already checked that, in desperation I tried including every permutation of these 2 ...

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED,

ok so apparently I did a mess with the inclusion of my own libraries.
after including winsock2.h in couple of other places I managed to compile it on 32 bit aswell.

Thanks for your time!